# Error while sending MMS using com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity

Tags: android, mms

I am getting following error when I try to send an MMS (I am suppressing  the list suggested application activity for composing the MMS) and my code looks like

```
Uri path = Uri.parse("file:///sdcard//page.jpg");

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND, path);
intent.putExtra("address", “<<phone number>>”);
intent.putExtra("subject", "dfsdfsdfds");
intent.putExtra("sms_body", "hello");
intent.setClassName(
    "com.android.mms",
    "com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity"
);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, path);     
intent.setType("image/*"); 
startActivity(intent);
```

Device: Sony Xperia 
SDK version: 2.1

```
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2205): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2205): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.mms/com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException 
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2205): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663) 
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2205): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679) 
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2205): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125) 
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2205): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033) 
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2205): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2205): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123) 
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2205): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627) 
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2205): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2205): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521) 
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2205): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868) 
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2205): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626) 
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2205): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2205): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2205): at com.android.mms.ui.UriImage.(UriImage.java:68) 
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2205): at com.android.mms.model.ImageModel.initModelFromUri(ImageModel.java:82) 
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2205): at com.android.mms.model.ImageModel.(ImageModel.java:64) 
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2205): at com.android.mms.data.WorkingMessage.changeMedia(WorkingMessage.java:461) 
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2205): at com.android.mms.data.WorkingMessage.setAttachment(WorkingMessage.java:362) 
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2205): at com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity.addImage(ComposeMessageActivity.java:2640) 
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2205): at com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity.addAttachment(ComposeMessageActivity.java:2776) 
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2205): at com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity.handleSendIntent(ComposeMessageActivity.java:2705) 
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2205): at com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity.initialize(ComposeMessageActivity.java:1743) 
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2205): at com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity.onCreate(ComposeMessageActivity.java:1678) 
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2205): at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047) 
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2205): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627) 
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2205): ... 11 more
```

Please help me out on this ?

Comment: someone is null....may be path Please check with                             System.out.println("path :: " + path);

Comment: I've faced same problem. Didn't you solved that yet?

Comment: This problem is device specific. I found this problem in SAMSUNG tablet and same code runs successfully in HTC devices. This is due to Android OS code customization according to their needs. The class which I am calling may not exist in SAMSUNG based android OS.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is a null pointer as indicated by

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

From the code you have posted it looks like path is the problem. From your stack it is trying to set the attachment based on the URI. I doubt it is device specific as per your comment. I think the problem is simply that "Page.jpg" is not on the SDCard.